# Use grep inside of a loop that calls on a list of different strings sequentially to change part of the grep

Tags: r

I would like to write a loop (or use one of the apply) that calls sequentially on a list that contains a string of both years and values and creates a new variable each time.  I would appreciate the help in making this code more efficient in a simple way.

My data is something like this (but with hundreds of different names and prefixes over a range of years and PRE and POST):

```
df<-data.frame(matrix(rnorm(5),5,5))
colnames(df)<- c("ip_cr_2011", "ip_cr_2012", "ip_dr_2011", "ip_mri_PRE", "la_dr_2012")
df
   ip_cr_2011 ip_cr_2012 ip_dr_2011 ip_mri_PRE la_dr_2012
1   0.3479453  0.3479453  0.3479453  0.3479453  0.3479453
2   0.7020550  0.7020550  0.7020550  0.7020550  0.7020550
3  -0.3531478 -0.3531478 -0.3531478 -0.3531478 -0.3531478
4   1.5450825  1.5450825  1.5450825  1.5450825  1.5450825
5   0.1163896  0.1163896  0.1163896  0.1163896  0.1163896
```

What I tried to do is something like this

```
yearlist<-c("2011","2012","2013","2014","PRE","POST")
for (i in yearlist){
  DFtotals$iptot_[i]<-rowSums(df[,grep("ip.*[[i]]", names(df))])
}
```

what I am doing now.. is just copying and pasting in all the year numbers.

```
DFtotals$iptot_2011 <- rowSums(df[,grep("ip.*2011", names(df))])
DFtotals$iptot_2012 <- rowSums(df[,grep("ip.*2012", names(df))])
#etc...
DFtotals$iptot_PRE <- rowSums(df[,grep("ip.*PRE", names(df))])
```

df

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using regex you can extract the common part of column names that you want to group together.

```
sub('\\w+_\\w+_', '', names(df))
#[1] "2011" "2012" "2011" "PRE"  "2012"
#You can also use this regex
#sub('.*?(\\d+|PRE|POST).*', '\\1', names(df))
#Use the regex which suits the column names in your data.
```

You can use this in `split.default` to split the dataframe in list of dataframes by similar column names and use `rowSums` :

```
sapply(split.default(df,sub('\\w+_\\w+_', '', names(df))), rowSums, na.rm = TRUE)

#       2011   2012     PRE
#[1,] -0.607 -0.607 -0.3037
#[2,] -1.740 -1.740 -0.8699
#[3,]  0.217  0.217  0.1084
#[4,] -0.184 -0.184 -0.0919
#[5,]  0.254  0.254  0.1272
```

Comment: This is a smart way of thinking about it Ronak.  Because I am actually merging two regex searches, right?  I am looking for names:  "ip" and "la" in this case; and years: "2011", "2012", "PRE", and "POST", in the example that I gave.  But, how do I assign the output? I want that to be automatic and I want to use the regex searches that I have put into place to define the assigned output.  I would like to end up with a data frame with columns whose names look as follows:  DFtotals$iptot_2011 and DFtotals$iptot_2012, and DFtotal$latot_2012.

Comment: How about `DFtotal  <- sapply(split.default(df, sub('(\\w+)_\\w+_(\\w+)', '\\1_tot_\\2', names(df))), rowSums)`